# Linking error when compliling legacy Oracle OCI code

Tags: c++, oracle, api, oracle-call-interface

I have to make changes to a program using the legacy OCI library. To make myself familiar with the API I have tried to play with some sample code, however it fails to compile with the following linking errors:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   oclose(struct cda_def *)" (?oclose@@YAHPAUcda_def@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl oci_error(void)" (?oci_error@@YAXXZ) 1>main.obj
>   : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl oerhms(struct
>   cda_def *,short,unsigned char *,int)"
>   (?oerhms@@YAHPAUcda_def@@FPAEH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   oci_error(void)" (?oci_error@@YAXXZ) 1>main.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl oexec(struct cda_def *)"
>   (?oexec@@YAHPAUcda_def@@@Z) referenced in function _main 1>main.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl olog(struct
>   cda_def *,unsigned char *,unsigned char *,int,unsigned char
>   *,int,unsigned char *,int,unsigned int)" (?olog@@YAHPAUcda_def@@PAE1H1H1HI@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   ologof(struct cda_def *)" (?ologof@@YAHPAUcda_def@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl oci_error(void)" (?oci_error@@YAXXZ) 1>main.obj
>   : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl oopen(struct
>   cda_def *,struct cda_def *,unsigned char *,int,int,unsigned char
>   *,int)" (?oopen@@YAHPAUcda_def@@0PAEHH1H@Z) referenced in function _main 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl oparse(struct cda_def *,unsigned char *,int,int,unsigned int)" (?oparse@@YAHPAUcda_def@@PAEHHI@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   obndra(struct cda_def *,unsigned char *,int,unsigned char
>   *,int,int,int,short *,unsigned short *,unsigned short *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,unsigned char *,int,int)"
>   (?obndra@@YAHPAUcda_def@@PAEH1HHHPAFPAG3IPAI1HH@Z) referenced in
>   function _main

I have added the path ...\oci\lib\msvc to my project as an additional library location.

Im using:
Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.
Oracle 10.2.

What could be the problem?
All help appreciated

Comment: you did not add the oci.lib or other core lib, or you add wrong version of it (like 64 bit when compiling 32 bit or vice versa)

Comment: Actually i did almost everything well. However the OCI library was written in C and to use that in C++ I had to add extern "C" { ... } around the OCI includes.